# Groebner base optimal solution with inequalities

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, integer-programming, maple, groebner-basis

I have to solve the following optimization problem using Groebner bases. The objective function is

$$x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4$$

with constraints

$$x_1+x_2 \ge 1, \qquad x_1+x_2+x_3 \ge 1, \qquad x_2+x_3+x_4 \ge 1, \qquad x_1+x_3+x_4 \ge 1$$

I tried in Maple, Mathematica and Matlab without success. Could someone help me with this? I have no idea.

Comment: Are you familiar with the simplex algorithm ?

Comment: Even if you are not, this is not very difficult. Note to begin with that the two first constraints imply $x_3 = 0$ (assuming you are minimizing).

Comment: @Kuifje it has to be with Groebner bases. I have problem with 30 inequlities (all have to be binary {0,1}) and all inequalities are >=1 but if I put for example (just example) in Maple

F := [x1+x2-1, x1+x2+x7+x30-1, ..., x1^2-x1 ]; (the last one is there because of binary values) and after that I create Groebner basis, I get that system has no solutions, but I know it has.